# Adding link to Image in axcs.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net

What i want to do is add link to an image.

The code is whenever isPackage is true. the image visibility on my axcs file will be visible. but what i want to do make the image visible and also give link similar on the label below.

This is the code for my isPackage.

```
 if (wli.isPackage)
     ((Image)dvLineItems.FindControl("imgPack")).Visible = true;
```

This is the Code for the label.

```
((Label)dvLineItems.FindControl("Product")).Text = "<a href='#' onClick='javascript:ImageUpWindow(" + wli.OrderNumber + ")'>" + wli.ProductNo + "</a>";
```

How can i do that? Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would use a link button in this case and then set the Command and Command Argument properties to your specifications.

Comment: Yeah it's easy to give link the the axcs file but what i need is link it throught my ascx.cs file because i need to pass parameter on the onclick function like this label. i'm asking if it's possible to do it here. with that kind of code?